# Any alternative solution for getting this work? Php code is not working right but mysql code is working

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have been struggling with the following codes for long time now. I am new in PHP. This code of mysql is 100% working in phpmyadmin. I am using `<?php echo $row['Rank'];?>` but I only get 1 for all students. But the sql code is working fine. I have made the sql fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24855/1 Please help me.

```sql
Select Distinct regd, Roll_no, Name_of_Student, Test_date,
English, f_eng, Mizo, f_mz,  Hindi, f_hn,  Mathematics,  f_maths, SS, f_ss, Science, 
f_sc, score, fmscore, perc, Rank FROM (SELECT *, IF(@marks = (@marks := score), @auto, 
@auto := @auto + 1) AS Rank FROM
(SELECT regd, Roll_no, Name_of_Student, Test_date,
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'English', Mark_score, 0 ) ) AS English,
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'English', Full_mark, 0 ) ) AS f_eng, 
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'Mizo', Mark_score, 0 ) ) AS Mizo,
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'Mizo', Full_mark, 0 ) ) AS f_mz, 
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'Hindi', Mark_score, 0 ) ) AS Hindi,
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'Hindi', Full_mark, 0 ) ) AS f_hn, 
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'Mathematics', Mark_score, 0 ) ) AS Mathematics, 
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'Mathematics', Full_mark, 0 ) ) AS f_maths, 
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'SS', Mark_score, 0 ) ) AS SS,
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'SS', Full_mark, 0 ) ) AS f_ss, 
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'Science', Mark_score, 0 ) ) AS Science,
SUM( IF( `Subject` = 'Science', Full_mark, 0 ) ) AS f_sc,
SUM(Full_mark) AS fmscore,
SUM(Mark_score) AS score, SUM(Mark_score)/SUM(Full_mark)*100 as perc FROM cxexam,
(SELECT @auto := 0, @marks := 0) AS init GROUP BY regd ORDER BY score DESC) t) AS result where Test_date between '2013-07-01' and '2013-07-31'
```

Here is the PHP part. It seems OK. It also echo everything correctly except that it does not output the Rank correctly. In the rank row it only displays  `1` as rank for all students. You can understand from the below code what I am trying to achieve. I really need your help. I know you guys are well familiar with such problem.

```
<table width="800" border="1" class="tablestyle" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="6">
<tr> 
    <th align="center" width="80">Roll No</th>
    <th align="center" width="100">Name_of_Student</th>
    <th align="center" width="40">English</th>
    <th align="center" width="55">Mizo</th>
    <th align="center" width="55">Hindi</th>
    <th align="center" width="55">Math</th>
    <th align="center" width="70">SS</th>
    <th align="center" width="40">Science</th>
     <th align="center" width="70">FM</th>
      <th align="center" width="70">MO</th>
      <th align="center" width="40">Percentage</th>
      <th align="center" width="40">Rank</th>
      <th align="center" width="40">Result</th>

</tr>
<?php 
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
?>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row['Roll_no'];?></td>
    <td align="left"><?php echo $row['Name_of_Student'];?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row['English'];?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row['Mizo'];?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row['Hindi'];?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row['Mathematics'];?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row['SS'];?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row['Science'];?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row['fmscore'];?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row['score'];?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo number_format($row['perc'],0);?>%</td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Rank']; ?></td>
    <td><?php 
    if ($row['English']/$row['f_eng']*100>=40 && $row['Mizo']/$row['f_mz']*100>=40 && $row['Hindi']/$row['f_hn']*100>=40 && $row['Mathematics']/$row['f_math']*100>=40 && $row['SS']/$row['f_ss']*100>=40 && $row['Science']/$row['f_sc']*100>=40)
   {
   echo "<font color=green>Passed</font>";
   }
   else 
   {
   echo "<font color=red>Failed</font>";
   }
   ?></td>

</tr>
<?php
    }
?>
</table>
```

The parts which are not working: `rank` and `result`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your sql code (e.g. never mix `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`, use `WHERE` in inner select etc). That being said your query should look something like

```sql
SELECT regd, Roll_no, Name_of_Student, Test_date,
       English, f_eng, 
       Mizo, f_mz,  
       Hindi, f_hn,  
       Mathematics,  f_maths, 
       SS, f_ss, 
       Science, f_sc, 
       score, fmscore, perc, Rank 
FROM 
(
  SELECT t.*, IF(@p = score, @n, @n := @n + 1) AS Rank, @p := score 
    FROM
  (
    SELECT regd, Roll_no, Name_of_Student, Test_date,
            SUM(IF(Subject = 'English'    , Mark_score, 0)) English,
            SUM(IF(Subject = 'English'    , Full_mark,  0)) f_eng, 
            SUM(IF(Subject = 'Mizo'       , Mark_score, 0)) Mizo,
            SUM(IF(Subject = 'Mizo'       , Full_mark,  0)) f_mz, 
            SUM(IF(Subject = 'Hindi'      , Mark_score, 0)) Hindi,
            SUM(IF(Subject = 'Hindi'      , Full_mark,  0)) f_hn, 
            SUM(IF(Subject = 'Mathematics', Mark_score, 0)) Mathematics, 
            SUM(IF(Subject = 'Mathematics', Full_mark,  0)) f_maths, 
            SUM(IF(Subject = 'SS'         , Mark_score, 0)) SS,
            SUM(IF(Subject = 'SS'         , Full_mark,  0)) f_ss, 
            SUM(IF(Subject = 'Science'    , Mark_score, 0)) Science,
            SUM(IF(Subject = 'Science'    , Full_mark,  0)) f_sc,
            SUM(Full_mark) fmscore,
            SUM(Mark_score) score, 
            SUM(Mark_score) / SUM(Full_mark) * 100 perc 
      FROM cxexam, (SELECT @n := 0, @p := 0) n 
     WHERE Test_date BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2013-07-31'
     GROUP BY regd 
     ORDER BY score DESC
  ) t
) r
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba01d/2)** demo

Now php code

```php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('dbname', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

$sql = "
    SELECT regd, Roll_no, Name_of_Student, Test_date,
           English, f_eng, 
           Mizo, f_mz,  
           Hindi, f_hn,  
           Mathematics,  f_maths, 
           SS, f_ss, 
           Science, f_sc, 
           score, fmscore, perc, Rank 
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT t.*, IF(@p = score, @n, @n := @n + 1) AS Rank, @p := score 
        FROM
      (
        SELECT regd, Roll_no, Name_of_Student, Test_date,
                SUM(IF(Subject = 'English'    , Mark_score, 0)) English,
                SUM(IF(Subject = 'English'    , Full_mark,  0)) f_eng, 
                SUM(IF(Subject = 'Mizo'       , Mark_score, 0)) Mizo,
                SUM(IF(Subject = 'Mizo'       , Full_mark,  0)) f_mz, 
                SUM(IF(Subject = 'Hindi'      , Mark_score, 0)) Hindi,
                SUM(IF(Subject = 'Hindi'      , Full_mark,  0)) f_hn, 
                SUM(IF(Subject = 'Mathematics', Mark_score, 0)) Mathematics, 
                SUM(IF(Subject = 'Mathematics', Full_mark,  0)) f_maths, 
                SUM(IF(Subject = 'SS'         , Mark_score, 0)) SS,
                SUM(IF(Subject = 'SS'         , Full_mark,  0)) f_ss, 
                SUM(IF(Subject = 'Science'    , Mark_score, 0)) Science,
                SUM(IF(Subject = 'Science'    , Full_mark,  0)) f_sc,
                SUM(Full_mark) fmscore,
                SUM(Mark_score) score, 
                SUM(Mark_score) / SUM(Full_mark) * 100 perc 
          FROM cxexam, (SELECT @n := 0, @p := 0) n 
         WHERE Test_date BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2013-07-31'
         GROUP BY regd 
         ORDER BY score DESC
      ) t
    ) r";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(!$result) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "{$row['regd']} - {$row['Rank']}<br>";
}
```

Output (as expected):

```
40 - 1
2  - 2
3  - 2
20 - 3
```

Comment: I will test and let you know what I come up with.

Comment: one more thing. how do I format the table? Please just give me an example.

Answer (score 1):

For the ranking part this is 100% working. Seems you don't know php very well.

```
<?php 
$rank = $prevScore = 0; 
{     
$count++; // always increment
if ($row_dep['perc'] > $prevScore) {
//whenever a non-tie occurs the my rank catches up
$my_rank = $count;
$rank = $count;
} else {
//whenever a tie occurs, just use the my rank
$rank = $my_rank;
}  
$prevScore = $row_dep['perc'];   
echo $rank;
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in this part of code:-
SELECT *, IF(@marks = (@marks := score), @auto, 
@auto := @auto + 1)
You need to make sure the logic is correct.

Comment: I have double checked the sql code and also tested in phpmyadmin. it is working perfect. The problem rather seems to be in the php code but could not figure it out.