# How to increment count in php with two conditions?

Tags: php, mysql, count

I want to increment `$count` with a given value in a descending manner. If the given values have the same number, $count will stop incrementing and start incrementing if the next value is different. Maybe I can't explain it clearly here. Look at my code and you will see and understand what I am trying to achieve.

```
<?php
$count=1;

if(current $row['perc']==next $row['perc'])//
{
echo "";//stop incrementing and output the same count. Because current perc and next perc have the same value, I don't know how to make echo here.
}
else
{
echo $count++; //start incrementing
}
?>
```

I want to achive something like

`id    position`

```
`101    1`

`102    2`

`103    2'
```

I am trying to count the position based on value that I pull from my database. If two value has same `perc` they will have the same position.

Comment: You better explain what are you trying to achieve. Maybe you just want to get a count on distinct values in column `perc`? Better yet show sample data and desired output.

Comment: I'm thinking he wants to print a group header enumerating the groups.

Comment: @peterm I will edit my post.

Comment: @peterm you where right

Comment: @Orangepill I am pulling `perc` from mysql and put it in mysql fetch array. I just want to put count increment based on values from column `perc`. But if some rows in `perc` column have same value, I want to stop the increment and use the current count and continue when value in the next row is less than the current row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can do it in MySql with a query like this

```sql
SELECT id, position
  FROM
(
  SELECT id, IF(@p = perc, @n , @n := @n + 1) position, @p := perc
    FROM Table1 t, (SELECT @n := 0, @p := 0) n
   ORDER BY perc DESC
) q
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c17a8/15)** demo

Comment: @perterm thanks for your help. I really need the php solution for my question. php sometimes does not handle Sql variables properly especially in mysql fetch array. So Please can you show me how I could achieve using php? You may know that I want to use `perce` as a condition for incrementing count.

Comment: @Zuala First of all there shouldn't be any problems with this type of query on calling side. Now to help you with php code you need to show all relevant code where you execute your query and iterate over the result set.

Comment: I have already had the same question asked in another title here. Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764305/any-alternative-solution-for-getting-this-work-php-code-is-not-working-right-bu/17764331?noredirect=1#17764331. Here you can you see the problem with mysql. I am thinking of the php solution now as count incrementing.

Comment: I have used this for returning one row, but have no idea for pulling all the rows.


`$i = 0;
$j = 0;
$data = array();
while($row_myrank = mysql_fetch_assoc($myrank))
    {
    $data[$i] = $row_myrank;
    if(isset($data[$i - 1]) && $data[$i - 1]['TOTALSCORE'] == $data[$i]['TOTALSCORE'])
    {
       $data[$i]['Rank'] = $j;
    }else{
       $data[$i]['Rank'] = ++$j;
    }
       $i++;
    }
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
 if($value['regd'] == $regd)
 {
   echo $value['Rank'];
 }
}`

Comment: @Zuala See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17769828/1920232) to your previous question. Like I said there is no problems with fetching values from correctly working query even with deprecated `mysql_*` extension.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using php do while to echo all the data like I did in my previous post, But I am getting one more row. I don't why I get this. Try it yourself and I think you will also see the problem.

Comment: @Zuala There is obviously an error in your php code. Without seeing it it's hard to tell what is wrong with it.